# MaskedTextBox Minimum/Maximum Lengths

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5, maskedtextbox

I have a masked textbox with the need to have a min/max length set on them. When these conditions are met a button becomes enabled.

I was thinking of handling the TextChanged event to determine the length of the entered text and set the buttons enabled value.

Is there a better approach?

```
 btnOK.Enabled = txtDataEntry.Text.Length >= MinDataLength && txtDataEntry.Text.Length <= MaxDataLength;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which approach could be even simpler than what you are suggesting?

```
myTextBox.Textchanged+=(s,o)=>{ myButton.Enabled = myTextBox.Length==10; };
```

Comment: See updated question. How do I prevent them entering more than the max length?

Comment: There is a *MaxLength* property in TextBox which is made for this case :)

Answer (score 0):

IMO TextChanged event is good place to handle this feature condition.

**Update**

Do it in  KeyPress event like this:

```
maskedtxtbox.KeyPress => (s , ev ) { 
                    if(maskedtxtbox.Length > 9)
                    {
                       //This prevent from key to go to control
                       e.Handled =true;
                       button1.Enabled = true;
                    } 
                 };
```

Comment: See updated question. How do I prevent them entering more than the max length?

Comment: it tells OS that key has been handled and dosent need to go further for processing..(which is go and draw character in control). Look here for detail http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled.aspx

Comment: problem is with length is that its always 1 behind so I cant enable the button if its length <= 10 as this will only be true once 11 chars have been typed in

Answer (score 0):

// At your texbox valdating Event

```
    private void textBox4_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        if (tb != null)
        {
            int i=tb.Text.Length;
            //Set your desired minimumlength here '7'
            if (i<7)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Too short Password");
                return;

            }
        }
        else

        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```