# How to format textbox to display SSN as the user types

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox which I would like to format in real time: `###-##-####` as the user types.

I have the following code:

```
private bool bFlag;

private void tbSSN_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = tbSSN.Text;
    if (!bFlag) 
    {
        if (str.Length == 3 || str.Length == 6) 
        {
            tbSSN.Text += "-";
        bFlag = true;
        tbSSN.SelectionStart = tbSSN.Text.Length;
        } 
        else if (str.Length > 11) 
        {
            tbSSN.Text = tbSSN.Text.Remove(tbSSN.Text.Length - 1);
        tbSSN.SelectionStart = tbSSN.Text.Length;
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        bFlag = false;
    }
}
```

The only issue is, when I hit backspace and try to enter the numbers again, it is allowing me to enter this format: `#####--####` or `##-#####-##`

I know I have to add a `KeyPress` event to ensure the above issue is resolved, but I am not sure how I would add it.

How would I code the `KeyPress` event?

It is a WinForm application.

Comment: What kind of application you are targeting ? WinForm, WPF ASP.Net ?

Comment: Updating my question. It is a WinForm

Comment: Have you tried text box masking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of normal TextBox and define a [Mask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your TextBox.

```
yourMaskedTextBox.Mask = "000-00-0000";
```

Comment: Will it be inside the TextChanged or KeyPress or both?

Comment: @SiKni8, no need for these events. Just define the mask and it will work.

Comment: @Habib, Thanks. Don't see the `.Mask` Is there a namespace or DLL that I have to import?

Comment: @SiKni8, you have to replace your existing TextBox, with `MaskedTextBox`. You can place that on designer, remove your existing TextBox

Comment: Yes I just noticed it. Thanks. Am about to test it out :)

Comment: The issue with that I am seeing is, when I check the length of the textbox without entering anything is 7 (SSN are 9 digit long). How would I validate the textbox to ensure the user entered all the numbers?

Comment: @SiKni8, you need to check the `Length` of your Masked text box, see this answer if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/4876409/961113

Comment: I am already checking the length. Thank you. Accepted your answer :)