# Format SSN as user types

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

Using Visual Studio 2012 Lightswitch C# Silverlight Web.

I would like to auto format a textbox like ###-##-#### when a user types in #########. Very similar to how the compute property works in Lightswitch except i need this in a textbox.

Example: I would like to achieve something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24246640/2658820) except in Lightswitch.

Do i need to create a custom business type or can this be done directly in Lightswitch?

Comment: Have you considered using 3 textboxes instead?

Comment: There is no MaskedTextBox in Silverlight, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24822/Silverlight-Super-TextBox-ComboBox-Masked-TextBox) project describes how to build your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

As usual, Beth Massi explained how to do this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/11/11/common-validation-rules-in-lightswitch-business-applications.aspx). No need for custom business types or custom silverlight controls.

From my Application Data i created a _Validate method on my SSN field. Code looks like this

```
    partial void SSN_Validate(EntityValidationResultsBuilder results)
    {
        if (this.SSN != null)
        {
            if (this.SSN.Length == 9 && !this.SSN.Contains("-"))
            {
                this.SSN = this.SSN.Substring(0, 3) + "-" + this.SSN.Substring(3, 2) + "-" + this.SSN.Substring(5);
            }

            if(!Regex.IsMatch(this.SSN, @"^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$"))
            {
                results.AddPropertyError("Please enter a valid SSN (i.e. 123-45-6789).");
            }
        }            
    }
```